# How do I make my cursor visible?

Tags: mouse

I'm using RPi OS, my cursor/mouse pointer is not visible. When I move the mouse I can see buttons highlight, but can not see the cursor. How do I make it visible?

Comment: How did you change it? I know of no OS that has it off by default.

Comment: I don't know how it got changed. I downloaded an automotive monitoring file (which I haven't unzipped) and then noticed that it wasn't there.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting to see if it comes back?

Comment: Yes,  I have also gone in and tried changing the cursor color and look. Still didn't make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the automotive monitoring file because it must be that it can have a faulty program(s) that was set to run on startup.

Comment: Should work (though I don't know what that means or is).